# Unable to access software sources

Tags: 12.10, software-center, software-sources

[image: Software sources are inaccesible]

Also when trying to access it from Ubuntu software center the entry that says "Edit software sources" is greyed out. Finally when running

`cp /usr/share/applications/software-properties-gtk.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`

I receive the following message

```
cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/applications/software-properties-gtk.desktop': No such file or directory
```

And when I run

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/software-properties-gtk.desktop
```

It opens a blank text file in geddit.

How can I get a software sources back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package for software source is the **"software-properties-gtk"**

Go to **"Ubuntu Software Center"** and search for the package **"software-properties-gtk"**, if the package is not installed , please install it.

[image]

Regards.

Comment: In my 14.04 setup, I couldn't find this package through the Software Center. Had to run `sudo apt-get install software-properties-gtk` on terminal.